# Elasticsearch find match containing only words from list in any order

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to get elasticsearch to find all keywords which contains particular words but only those.

My attempt is:

```
{ "fields": ["keyword_norm"],
  "size": 100,
  "query":
  {
      "bool" : {
          "must" : [ {"match": {"keyword_norm": "shoe" }}, 
                     {"match": {"keyword_norm": "nike" } }
                  ]
  }
}
}
```

For such a query it returns correctly:

```
 shoe nike
 nike shoe
```

but also

```
 buy nike shoe
 nike shoe buy
```

How can I filter out those other words?

Comment: Can you post your mapping?

Answer (score 2):

One option if you know the other words is to add a `must_not` clause to your [bool query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html):

```
{
  "fields": ["keyword_norm"],
  "size": 100,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"match": {"keyword_norm": "shoe" }}, 
        {"match": {"keyword_norm": "nike" }}
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {"match": {"keyword_norm": "buy" }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Otherwise you can extend your original query and add a [script filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-filter.html).

```
{
  "fields": ["keyword_norm"],
  "size": 100,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "must": [
          {"match": {"keyword_norm": "shoe" }}, 
          {"match": {"keyword_norm": "nike" }}
        ]
      },
      "filter": {
        "script": "#psuedo code-> words = doc['keyword_norm'].value.split(' '); for (word : words) { if(!terms.contains(word)) return 0; } return 1;",
        "params": {
          "terms": ["shoe", "nike"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```